# Using Function with replace with the US-350 to 350 How to?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling

I am trying to replace the US- 350 with 350 in the Label Expression but I am stuck how to do that...

I am looking at the help here for the function:
Function FindLabel ( [LABELFIELD] ) 
FindLabel = replace([LABELFIELD], ", ", vbnewline) 
End Function

This is what I did this :

Function FindLabel ( [ID] )
FindLabel = replace ( [ID], US- 350, 350)
End Function

no luck ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind  I figured it out.

Function FindLabel ( [ID] )

FindLabel = replace( [ID],"US-350",350)

End Function